# Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, java

I am trying to install a Java application on a Debian 8.1 server and I keep getting a "Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException" error.

I have installed Java8 from oracle, set JAVA_HOME to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", and cleared up a caberra-gtk-module dependency issue, but I am still getting the same issue and am at a bit of a loss now.

I have isntalled every libxp library I could find ( libxpm4-dbg libxp6-dbg libxp6 libxplc0.3.13 libxpa-dev libxpm-dev libxpp3-java libxpa1 libxp-dev libxpp2-java libxplc0.3.13-dev libxpm4)

I have tried both OpenJRE and Java8 from oracle.

I have attached the error message below. Any ideas?

---

Stack Trace:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/install.dir.27633/Linux/resource/jre/lib/i386/libawt.so: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.DebugHelper.(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.g(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.h(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Comment: Try with OpenJDK instead of Oracle Java.

Comment: I originally was using OpenJDK and ran into the same problem, that is when I switched from OpenJDK to Oracle Java.

Comment: Well after trying OpenJDK again and not having any success, removed all remnants of Java from the system and reinstalled Java8 from Oracle and I am not getting a slightly difference error. I am changing the error code listed above.

Comment: This is something different.  You now need the Xp library to be installed for Java to work at all.